# How to disable offline persistence with react-redux-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, redux-thunk, react-redux-firebase

I have a web application with React, Redux that connects to the Firebase's Realtime Database. Implementation uses react-redux-firebase library and it works.

Out of the box, if the app goes temporarily offline, changes to store are saved locally and are then executed once online again. The feature is called "offline persistence" by Firebase. I want to turn this off - if the application is offline, no actions should work and later, when internet is reconnected, no changes should be pushed to server.

How can I do this? I can't find it in react-redux-firebase's documentation or configuration. Neither switching from Realtime Database to Firestore changes this. As a side problem, the app writes errors to the console while offline. Everything works, but once again, I don't know how to turn these logs off.

```
WebSocketConnection.ts:183 WebSocket connection to 'wss...' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
WebSocketConnection.open @ WebSocketConnection.ts:183
(anonymous) @ Connection.ts:145
BrowserPollConnection.ts:745 GET https://... net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether the Firebase client is connected to the server by listening for the `.info/connected` node. When this is the case, you can prevent your code from sending any write operations to the database.

For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: While this may be used to detect whether we're connected to the Firebase, this doesn't stop the errors being printed in the console when we lose the connection. The errors are being printed even when I am not writing to Firebase, simply because I am listening to the changes on data, which can't be accessed while offline. The code you link to doesn't prevent that.

Comment: If you want us to help troubleshoot messages you see in the console, please edit your question to include those messages.